# Why is the script run twice?

Tags: vue.js

Here is a minimal example: https://jsfiddle.net/kxbufL80/.

```
<main>
    <script type="application/javascript">console.log("Why twice?")</script>
</main>
```

And how to prevent this?

Comment: Don't inject scripts into the DOM where you will mount your Vue instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The markup that contains `<main>` and your custom `<script>` is executed immediately upon loading the page (before Vue even runs), then again when Vue mounts onto `<main>`.

Assuming you can't move the `<script>` tag outside `<main>`, a workaround is to remove the `<script>` in the `beforeCreate` hook:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "main",
  beforeCreate() {
    document.querySelector('main script').remove()
  }
})
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3wq8u0a/1/)

However, Vue templates should not contain `<script>` tags to begin with, and the development build should warn you of this in the browser console.